# ABAQUS STRI3 Element, local coordination system

Tags: mechanical-engineering, finite-element-method, abaqus

As you know ABAQUS have a triangle plate bending element named STRI3. After analysis (post-process) when user generate report for internal stress of those STRI3 elements, abaqus give the Cauchy stress values in local coordination system of each element.

About local coordination system and transformation, [In the documentation it is noted that](https://abaqus-docs.mit.edu/2017/English/SIMACAETHERefMap/simathe-c-trifacetshells.htm):

> A local orthonormal basis system, T1 and T2, is defined in the plane
> of each element in the reference configuration, using the standard
> Abaqus convention. S1 and S2 measure distance along T1 and T2

> [image]

> in the reference configuration. Figure 1. Triangular facet shell in
> the reference configuration.

In brief, it says orthonormal basis system is defined using the standard Abaqus convention, but i was not able to find the "Standard Abaqus Convention" for this orthonormal basis thing!

My question is how is this local coordination system defined? I need exact formula.

Thanks

Comment: For shell conventions, see https://abaqus-docs.mit.edu/2017/English/SIMACAEELMRefMap/simaelm-c-shelloverview.htm.  For more general conventions, see https://abaqus-docs.mit.edu/2017/English/SIMACAEMODRefMap/simamod-c-conventions.htm

Comment: @BiswajitBanerjee Thanks for the link. It contains definition of positive and negative surface (e.g. normals) but not information about local coordination system.

Comment: From the second link above: "The default local 1-direction is the projection of the global x-axis onto the surface. If the global x-axis is within 0.1° of being normal to the surface, the local 1-direction is the projection of the global z-axis onto the surface. The local 2-direction is then at right angles to the local 1-direction, so that the local 1-direction, local 2-direction, and the positive normal to the surface form a right-handed set (see Figure 1). The positive normal direction is defined in an element by the right-hand rotation rule going around the nodes of the element."

Comment: @BiswajitBanerjee since it is comment i cannot mark it as answer. thanks

Comment: Since it's software related, and can change based on the whims of Dassault Systemes, it does not deserve to be an answer.  If someone with patience writes out the actual equations, that can be an answer.

Comment: @BiswajitBanerjee, OK I'll turn to equation and answer my own question